# Overrule !important inline CSS

Tags: css

I am using the Wordpress plugins 'NextGEN Gallery' and 'JJ NextGen JQuery Carousel' because I'm trying to make a carousel that looks alot like the default looks of the last named plugin. The problem is that the plugin uses a div with a background image as a button and it gets this CSS:

```
div#about-jcarousel_container .jcarousel-skin-custom .jcarousel-prev-horizontal {
    top: 188px !important;  
}
```

Because of that, this doesn't work (the top: 0px part):

```
.jcarousel-skin-custom .jcarousel-prev-horizontal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgba(24, 16, 16, 0.43) url(prev-horizontal.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-position-y: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Where it gets nasty is that the 188px is never called anywhere, so I cannot just edit it to make it 0px but client side in the browser. So I've looked around and it seems that the plugin puts the 188px code in inline < style > tags. Because it has !important I can't just use !imporant in my template.css to overwrite it.

Is the another way to overrule the !important tags that are used inline? I realy would like the keep the plugin updateable.

Comment: AFAIK, You can use `!important` again for your styles.

Comment: You said that it has inline stile, yet you posted CSS rule. Are you sure about the first?

Comment: @Mr_Green I tried, when I do that, it gets overruled by the style tags, because it is also !important.

Comment: Try adding "div#about-jcarousel_container" to the second rule and see if that helps. Also ensure that the second rule is being loaded after the first rule. Only use !important to try and get it to work as a last resort.

Comment: @ PavloMykhalov Inline as in, the plugin puts it in the HTML head in style tags.

@ BillyMoat I have no control over the plugin's behavior without making it un-updateable. !important was my last resort, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to override `!important` is to use `!important` again further in the cascade, so put it in a CSS file after the jcarousel one.

Alternatively, edit jcarousel

Comment: This actually helped me alot, I tried to call the CSS file before the plugin because it would be first with !important, but apparently it is the other way around. I called my CSS file after the plugin and it worked!

Mr_Green had the same answer, but this one was first so.. yeah.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are referring the jcarousel css file after your .css file in your html file. Keep the reference of the jcarousel .css file before your stylesheet(.css file). Then you can use `!important` again to override the default jcarousel .css file style property.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the specificity of your code.  If possible look for an ID as maybe the parent. And add !important to your top element.

```
#ID .jcarousel-skin-custom .jcarousel-prev-horizontal {
position: absolute;
top: 0px!important;
left: 0px;
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
cursor: pointer;
background: rgba(24, 16, 16, 0.43) url(prev-horizontal.png) no-repeat 0 0;
background-position-y: 50%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's why the use of `!important` is discouraged. You can only override the `!important` with another `!important` and it's not always possible. When there are two rules with `!important` then the "most important" one is applied.

And the question now is, which one is more important?

1. inline styles are more important (e.g. `<div class="someclass" style="inline style"></div>`) than normal styles
2. more specific rules > less specific (#one .example tag .yeah > .yeah)
3. if two rules have the same priority, the last one applied wins

If you can't add a more important rule, then you can't override the `!important`. But you can use a script to add inline styles when the page is loaded. Example (with jQuery):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").css("color","blue");
});
</script>
```

Example without jQuery:

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("test").style.color = "yellow";
}
</script>
```

Comment: AFAIK in < style > tags is most important of all CSS, only thing overwriting it is with !important, but the bad thing is that the plugin uses both of those.

Comment: you can use a script to modify inline styles after all styles have been applied. It's not very elegant, but if you can't do anything better at least it is a solution.

Comment: How would I do that? Seems handy for the future.

After testing, !importent for inline or from included file are the same, just the last one is most important.

Comment: done, two example scripts added. you can override inline `!important` styles with that.

Comment: Don't use jQuery to override CSS. What if it fails to load? What if the user has javascript disabled? Always fix it with CSS if possible

Comment: @Andy I said "If you can't add a more important rule". Of course it is better to solve it with plain CSS, but it is not always possible.

Comment: @TheBronx It is always possible. `!important` at the very end of the cascade will over write anything.

Comment: how about inline styles with `!important`?

Comment: @TheBronx You shouldnt style inline, never mind `!important` inline. If that's the case, write better code instead of relying on jQuery to cover up your mess